# After command npm start "Missing script:start" error

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

When I typed **npm start** following error is given ;

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-109-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2

npm ERR! missing script: start
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

Following package.json works in the another server. I tried to deploy my nodejs app to another server.I succesfully installed the nodejs and npm.

Note: After installing npm there is no node_modules folder under the my project folder.

My package.json file is like;

```
{
  "name": "myapplication",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "myapplication",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",
    "dev": "pm2 start ecosystem.config.js",
    "pro": "pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "apn": "2.1.5",
    "async": "2.5.0",
    "body-parser": "1.17.2",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "callback2promise": "1.0.3",
    "cookie-parser": "1.4.3",
    "express": "4.15.4",
    "express-session": "1.15.5",
    "geolib": "2.0.23",
    "image-type": "3.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "7.4.3",
    "jimp": "0.2.28",
    "mkdirp": "0.5.1",
    "mongoose": "4.11.9",
    "morgan": "1.8.2",
    "multer": "1.3.0",
    "node-gcm": "0.14.6",
    "nodemailer": "4.1.0",
    "shortid": "2.2.8",
    "socket.io": "2.0.3",
    "socket.io-redis": "5.2.0",
    "twitter": "1.7.1",
    "underscore-node": "0.1.2",
    "bcrypt": "1.0.3" 
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "4.5.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with `npm start`? You need to create a `start` script then. As the message told you ... You only have `test`, `dev` and `pro`.

Comment: @eisbehr I want to download the modules.Now there is no node_modules folder.How can I download without npm start ? The same file works in the another server

Comment: You need to use `npm install` then, not `npm start`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download and install all modules in the `node_modules/` folder, you need to use `install` and not `start`. As `start` is not predefined by `npm`, you need to define a custom script for it, if you want to use the comment.

So `install` is the default command to download and install all modules, depending on you `package.json`:

```
$ npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

Just re-install the create-react-app package globally on your system using below command and it should work.

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

then create react app using below command

```
create-react-app <your app name>
```

then go to your app directory and run the "npm start" command.

Answer (score 0):

Change "test" into "start" in scripts dictionary as:

```
  {
    "name": "myapplication",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "myapplication",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
    "**start**": "mocha",
    "dev": "pm2 start ecosystem.config.js",
    "pro": "pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": 
  {
    "apn": "2.1.5",
    "async": "2.5.0",
    "body-parser": "1.17.2",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "callback2promise": "1.0.3",
    "cookie-parser": "1.4.3",
    "express": "4.15.4",
    "express-session": "1.15.5",
    "geolib": "2.0.23",
    "image-type": "3.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "7.4.3",
    "jimp": "0.2.28",
    "mkdirp": "0.5.1",
    "mongoose": "4.11.9",
    "morgan": "1.8.2",
    "multer": "1.3.0",
    "node-gcm": "0.14.6",
    "nodemailer": "4.1.0",
    "shortid": "2.2.8",
    "socket.io": "2.0.3",
    "socket.io-redis": "5.2.0",
    "twitter": "1.7.1",
    "underscore-node": "0.1.2",
    "bcrypt": "1.0.3" 
  },
  "devDependencies": 
  {
    "eslint": "4.5.0"
  }
}
```

This is the appropriate solution that has worked for me. I used

```
"scripts": 
{
     .
     .

    "**start**": "webpack-dev-server --open",

     .
     .
}
```

As I am using 'webpack' as a loader.

Answer (score -1):

Add a start script in the package.json file

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "No description",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "start": "node index.js"
    ...
  },
  "license": "Unlicense",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  }
}
```